# Facebook, Twitter sharing from public terminals

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

from my basic understanding in order to share a picture on Facebook or twitter, one needs to be logged into one's system.

How about if it's a public terminal, users take pictures from there and then hit share, would they be able to share it on their timeline from there, if then how?

Edit - The app provides some image filters and following that users would like to share it, what should be the strategy for social media integration for such app

Edit 2 - Getting flexibly and seeking any kind of social integration possibilities - we could have build our own Facebook page, an admin logged in and user can post the picture from there to our own Facebook page.

Comment: who would login with their facebook account on a public terminal?

Comment: yes I guess no one, but what are the options that we can provide for social integration to our app for the users? (the app has basically some special image filters that they'd like to share)

Comment: create a native installable app so users can install it on their phones

Comment: actually it's going to be touch based interactive large displays that are gonna run this app, phone app is not in the scope

Comment: then i am afraid there will be no good solution. people would indeed have to login with facebook to share, of course. and even if people do that, facebook usually detects those things as malicious (many logins from the same panel in a short amount of time).

Comment: any lateral thinking? for instance having app's own page, it's own Facebook application integrated with our app, and then sharing on it's wall and preferably tagging the user who uploaded

Comment: without user login, no tagging. without facebook login, no app login. you don´t get the user data without login.

Comment: we can let's say login the admin for this Facebook page and everyone who comes will get their photo posted on this page that belongs to the app, possible?

Comment: yes, that would be possible